# Docker Desktop on Windows 10 crashes on switching to Windows Containers

Tags: docker, docker-desktop

I've installed latest version which is Version: 2.1.0.4 (39773) as of today.

When I am switching to Windows Containers by clicking on right click menu of the docker status icon, I get following error after a while. I do have Hypder-V enabled on my machine.

Wondering if anyone experiencing this issue and what can the resolution be.

[image]

Attaching the log of docker for this

```
[14:45:57.808][VpnKit            ][Info   ] vpnkit.exe: 2 upstream DNS servers are configured

[14:45:57.808][VpnKit            ][Info   ] vpnkit.exe: New Gateway forward configuration: [{"protocol":"udp","external_port":53,"internal_ip":"127.0.0.1","internal_port":51700},{"protocol":"tcp","external_port":53,"internal_ip":"127.0.0.1","internal_port":58896}]

[14:45:57.808][VpnKit            ][Info   ] vpnkit.exe: Updating transparent HTTP redirection: {

[14:45:57.808][VpnKit            ][Info   ]   "exclude": "",

[14:45:57.808][VpnKit            ][Info   ]   "transparent_http_ports": [

[14:45:57.808][VpnKit            ][Info   ]     80

[14:45:57.808][VpnKit            ][Info   ]   ],

[14:45:57.808][VpnKit            ][Info   ]   "transparent_https_ports": [

[14:45:57.919][APIRequestLogger  ][Info   ] [467d6772-0076-4586-88cf-8fba2bdeb19b] GET http://unix/versions
[14:45:57.920][APIRequestLogger  ][Info   ] [467d6772-0076-4586-88cf-8fba2bdeb19b] GET http://unix/versions -> 200 OK took 0ms
[14:45:57.808][VpnKit            ][Info   ]     443

[14:45:57.808][VpnKit            ][Info   ]   ]

[14:45:57.808][VpnKit            ][Info   ] }

[14:45:57.808][VpnKit            ][Info   ] vpnkit.exe: C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts file has bindings for host.docker.internal gateway.docker.internal host.docker.internal gateway.docker.internal host.docker.internal gateway.docker.internal host.docker.internal gateway.docker.internal kubernetes.docker.internal

[14:45:57.909][ApiProxy          ][Info   ] time="2019-11-15T14:45:57+11:00" msg="ðŸ€ socket server listening : \\\\.\\pipe\\dockerGuiToDriver"
[14:45:57.924][ApiProxy          ][Info   ] time="2019-11-15T14:45:57+11:00" msg="docker proxy: ready"
[14:45:57.928][ApiProxy          ][Error  ] time="2019-11-15T14:45:57+11:00" msg="Unable to forward a named-pipe to the lifecycle-server: /forwards/expose/pipe returned unexpected status: 500"
[14:45:57.928][ApiProxy          ][Error  ] time="2019-11-15T14:45:57+11:00" msg="Unable to forward a named-pipe to the Linux docker engine: /forwards/expose/pipe returned unexpected status: 500"
[14:45:57.928][ApiProxy          ][Info   ] time="2019-11-15T14:45:57+11:00" level=info msg=waitForDockerUp
[14:45:57.928][ApiProxy          ][Info   ] time="2019-11-15T14:45:57+11:00" msg="ðŸ€ socket server starting : \\\\.\\pipe\\dockerGuiToDriver"
[14:45:57.928][ApiProxy          ][Info   ] time="2019-11-15T14:45:57+11:00" msg="Static DNS lookup table: map[docker-desktop.:19.16.65.3 docker-for-desktop.:19.16.65.3 docker.for.win.gateway.internal.:19.16.65.1 docker.for.win.host.internal.:19.16.65.2 docker.for.win.http.internal.:19.16.65.1 docker.for.win.localhost.:19.16.65.2 gateway.docker.internal.:19.16.65.1 host.docker.internal.:19.16.65.2 kubernetes.docker.internal.:19.16.65.3 vm.docker.internal.:19.16.65.3]"
[14:45:57.929][ApiProxy          ][Info   ] time="2019-11-15T14:45:57+11:00" msg="proxy >> HEAD /_ping\n"
[14:45:57.929][ApiProxy          ][Info   ] time="2019-11-15T14:45:57+11:00" msg="Writing C:\\Users\\AppData\\Roaming\\Docker\\gateway_forwards.json"
[14:45:57.931][ApiProxy          ][Info   ] time="2019-11-15T14:45:57+11:00" msg="proxy << HEAD /_ping (2.0048ms)\n"
[14:45:57.949][NamedPipeClient   ][Info   ] Received response for engine/start
[14:45:57.932][ApiProxy          ][Info   ] time="2019-11-15T14:45:57+11:00" msg="proxy >> GET /v1.40/info\n"
[14:45:57.932][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] error CloseWrite to: The pipe is being closed.
[14:45:57.939][ApiProxy          ][Info   ] time="2019-11-15T14:45:57+11:00" msg="proxy >> GET /v1.40/containers/json\n"
[14:45:57.941][ApiProxy          ][Info   ] time="2019-11-15T14:45:57+11:00" msg="proxy << GET /v1.40/containers/json (2.0037ms)\n"
[14:45:57.942][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] error CloseWrite to: The pipe is being closed.
[14:45:57.945][ApiProxy          ][Info   ] time="2019-11-15T14:45:57+11:00" msg="proxy << GET /v1.40/info (13.0036ms)\n"
[14:45:57.946][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] error CloseWrite to: The pipe is being closed.
[14:45:57.946][ApiProxy          ][Info   ] time="2019-11-15T14:45:57+11:00" msg="Docker is responding"
[14:45:57.949][DockerDaemonChecker][Info   ] Docker daemon is running
[14:45:57.949][NamedPipeServer   ][Info   ] engine/start done in 00:00:00.3189743.
[14:45:58.141][ApiProxy          ][Info   ] time="2019-11-15T14:45:58+11:00" msg="proxy >> HEAD /_ping\n"
[14:45:58.143][ApiProxy          ][Info   ] time="2019-11-15T14:45:58+11:00" msg="proxy << HEAD /_ping (2.0074ms)\n"
[14:45:58.144][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] error CloseWrite to: The pipe is being closed.
[14:45:58.177][ApiProxy          ][Info   ] time="2019-11-15T14:45:58+11:00" msg="proxy >> GET /v1.40/info\n"
[14:45:58.189][ApiProxy          ][Info   ] time="2019-11-15T14:45:58+11:00" msg="proxy << GET /v1.40/info (11.9924ms)\n"
[14:45:58.190][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] error CloseWrite to: The pipe is being closed.
[14:45:58.755][ApiProxy          ][Info   ] time="2019-11-15T14:45:58+11:00" msg="proxy >> HEAD /_ping\n"
[14:45:58.758][ApiProxy          ][Info   ] time="2019-11-15T14:45:58+11:00" msg="proxy << HEAD /_ping (3.0077ms)\n"
[14:45:58.759][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] error CloseWrite to: The pipe is being closed.
[14:45:58.783][ApiProxy          ][Info   ] time="2019-11-15T14:45:58+11:00" msg="proxy >> GET /v1.40/version\n"
[14:45:58.797][ApiProxy          ][Info   ] time="2019-11-15T14:45:58+11:00" msg="proxy << GET /v1.40/version (14.0121ms)\n"
[14:45:58.798][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] error CloseWrite to: The pipe is being closed.
[14:45:58.808][Notifications     ][Info   ] Docker Desktop is running
[14:45:58.813][Notifications     ][Error  ] Time out has expired and the operation has not been completed.
[14:45:58.828][NamedPipeClient   ][Info   ] Sending app/version()...
[14:45:58.829][NamedPipeClient   ][Info   ] Received response for app/version
[14:45:58.829][NamedPipeClient   ][Info   ] Sending diagnostics/gather()...
[14:45:58.829][NamedPipeServer   ][Info   ] app/version()
[14:45:58.829][NamedPipeServer   ][Info   ] app/version done in 00:00:00.
[14:45:58.830][NamedPipeServer   ][Info   ] diagnostics/gather()
[14:46:02.797][VpnKit            ][Info   ] vpnkit.exe: Gateway forwards file C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Docker\gateway_forwards.json has changed

[14:46:02.797][VpnKit            ][Info   ] vpnkit.exe: Reading gateway forwards file from C:\Users\ppData\Roaming\Docker\gateway_forwards.json

[14:46:02.799][VpnKit            ][Info   ] vpnkit.exe: New Gateway forward configuration: [{"protocol":"udp","external_port":53,"internal_ip":"127.0.0.1","internal_port":54694},{"protocol":"tcp","external_port":53,"internal_ip":"127.0.0.1","internal_port":59304}]

[14:46:13.196][CrashReport       ][Info   ] Diagnostics cancelled by user
[14:46:13.197][NamedPipeClient   ][Info   ] Sending app/version()...
[14:46:13.198][NamedPipeClient   ][Info   ] Received response for app/version
[14:46:13.198][NamedPipeClient   ][Info   ] Sending diagnostics/stop-gather()...
[14:46:13.199][NamedPipeClient   ][Info   ] Received response for diagnostics/stop-gather
[14:46:13.197][NamedPipeServer   ][Info   ] app/version()
[14:46:13.201][NamedPipeClient   ][Error  ] Unable to send diagnostics/gather: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
[14:46:13.202][CrashReport       ][Warning] Unable to gather diagnostics in Windows Service : (Object reference not set to an instance of an object.)
[14:46:13.198][NamedPipeServer   ][Info   ] app/version done in 00:00:00.0009991.
[14:46:13.204][CrashReport       ][Warning] Starting to gather diagnostics as User : 'C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\com.docker.diagnose.exe' gather.
[14:46:13.198][NamedPipeServer   ][Info   ] diagnostics/stop-gather()
[14:46:13.199][NamedPipeServer   ][Info   ] diagnostics/stop-gather done in 00:00:00.0010009.
[14:46:13.200][NamedPipeServer   ][Error  ] Unable to execute diagnostics/gather: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.    at Docker.Backend.BackendService.GatherDiagnostics()
   at Docker.Core.Pipe.NamedPipeServer.RunAction(String action, Object[] parameters)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Docker Client - Settings - Make sure below highlighted check box is on. "Expose daemon on ...." . I was facing exact same error and tried multiple other solution but this was the main trick.

[image]

Comment: this doesn't work with me; I keep getting errors when switching to Windows containers and I see in the log:

msg="open \\\\.\\pipe\\docker_engine_windows: The system cannot find the file specified."